# Pages not loading on PHP 5.4.4 w/ APC - Apache 2.4.2

Tags: php, apache, apc

I'm hoping someone can help me with this, as I've kinda hit a wall. Here's the situation:

I'm currently setting up a knowledge base using MediaWiki. I'm using XAMPP to aggregate my tools. The site itself is working fine, and coming along nicely.

I'm now trying to set up a cache to speed things up. I've opted to use PHP APC, as it is recommended for MediaWiki. The troubles started here.

Current versions are:

PHP: 5.4.4
Apache: 2.4.2 (apache2handler)
SQL: 5.5.25a
XAMPP: 1.8.0
MediaWiki 1.19.1

I am currently using Windows, so the first issue I had was finding the correct php_apc.dll file for my PHP. I tried numerous versions unsuccessfully (with log errors stating the .dll cannot be found). I eventually was able to secure a version which seems to work, APC 3.1.14 for PHP 5.4, downloaded from http://dev.freshsite.pl/php-accelerators/apc.html. It is the TS version, as this option is enabled on my PHP.

Now, with this presumably correct version of APC, Apache is now able to start fine. phpinfo() also shows the APC extension as available. The problem is now that no pages on the wiki will load. Precise situation is that:

- All pages on the Wiki do not load (IP/mediawiki/*)
- Pages on XMAPP itself do seem to load correclt (IP/XAMPP/*).
- Other utilities are not able to load either, (e.g. phpMyAdmin).

No error messages seem to be created either in apache logs or php logs. Now, I am by no means an expert on this.

I have confirmed that environment variables in Windows TMP and TEMP both point to the same folder (C:\WINNT\TEMP), on which I gave "everyone" full access rights.

Here is an image showing the phpinfo() for APC that I can see:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYHwP.png

Any ideas?

edit: I forgot to mention: there actually are 0kb sized files that seem to be related to APC being created under c:\winnt\temp. For instance, one of them is called ".apc.a02684".

Answer (score 0):

This has come up previously on the [MediaWiki Support Desk](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Thread%3aProject%3aSupport_desk/Fatal_Error_when_accessing_SpecialPages).  MediaWiki apparently doesn't run under Apache 2.4.